# Foundamental group of $n+1$ spheres in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ that touch two by two

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

How can i calculate the foundamental group of three $S^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that touches two by two in one point (if you take any two spheres, they touch only in one point) ?

I know that is $\mathbb{Z}$ but i'm not able to formalize it using van Kampen.

How changes the foundamental group, and the application of van Kampen theorem, if you have $n+1$ $S^{n}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ that touches two by two in one point?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your space is homotopically equivalent to a circle with three spheres attached to it at different points. Like this picture (the filled in circles are spheres, the last one is just a circle):
[image: mad paint skills]

Now apply Van Kampen's theorem three times and the fact that $\pi_1(S^2) = 0$ to show that the fundamental group of the space is the fundamental group of the circle drawn in black, that is, $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Now yes :) .. by the way i can immediatly conclude retracting the three spheres in one point?

Comment: Spheres are not contractible. You can't contract them to a point but you should be able to figure out good open sets on which to use Van Kampen's theorem.

Comment: Ok, yes i see the open sets. The generalization is similar?

Comment: Pretty much, the combinatorics is just a bit more complicated (for example you get a tetrahedron when $n=3$).

Answer (score 1):

If you know that fundamental group depends only on the 2-skeleton, you can glue a 3-cell in the interior of each sphere. From a family $X$ of spheres, you get a family $\tilde{X}$ of closed balls. Now, $\tilde{X}$ retracts by deformation on a circle, so $$\pi_1(X) \simeq \pi_1(\tilde{X}) \simeq \pi_1(\mathbb{S}^1) \simeq \mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: unfortunately i don't know what 2-skeleton is. There is an elementary proof using van kampen?

Comment: You mean you can glue a *three*-cell, not a 2-cell in the interior of each sphere.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Sure, I edited my answer. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @camascers: Najib Idrissi gave you a hint, no?